# ArrayIndexOutOfBoounds error

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a new problem today, my array comes up with an out of bounds error, not sure why

```
package christophers;

import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Rikus21
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] anArray;
        int numNums = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input the number of terms in the array, integers only"));
        while(numNums > 10000||numNums <= 0)
        {
            if(numNums > 10000)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Array too large, insert a smaller number", "Heading", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                numNums = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input the number of terms in the array"));
            }
            else
            {
                if(numNums <= 0)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Array too small, insert a larger number", "", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        }
        anArray = new int[numNums];
        for(int j = 0; j <= numNums; j++)
        {
            anArray[j] = (int) (Math.random()*10001);
        }    
        Arrays.sort(anArray);
        System.out.println(anArray);
    }

}
```

Please advise

Comment: for(int j = 0; j < numNums; j++)

Comment: How do I print out the entire array now?

Comment: Arrays.toString (anArray);

Comment: It would be helpful if you give as a stacktrace as well

Comment: Please explain, or suggest somewhere where I could research stacktrace?

Comment: You all ready are printing the array by calling System.out.println(anArray); Since you array if of type int (which already has a toString method defined), when you write sysOut on your array the toString of each element in the array gets called if none other is defined for the array.

Comment: So how would I define  each element to reproduce each individual int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start your iteration at index 0 you have to stop before the length of it. You just have to do a strictly less than:

```
for(int j = 0; j < numNums; j++) {

}
```

You were getting the error on the `anArray[j]` when `j` was equal to `numNums`, because the first item is `anArray[0]` and the last one will be `anArray[numNums - 1]`, thus `anArray[numNums] was outside the bounds of your array.`

Answer (score 0):

Array iteration in java starts with 0 and ends with n-1 , where n is the size of array. If you declare an array as

```
 anArray = new int[numNums];
```

then make sure the iteration is between 0 and numNums-1, therefore change your for loop to

```
for(int j = 0; j < numNums; j++)
    {
        anArray[j] = (int) (Math.random()*10001);
    }
```

Comment: thanks, I've already changed the for loop

Answer (score 0):

The array contains `numNums` items, so if you start with an index `0` the last item in the array will have an index `numNums - 1`. 
So the `for-loop` should either be:

```
for(int j = 0; j < numNums; j++){
  ...
}
```

or

```
for(int j = 0; j <= numNums - 1; j++){
  ...
}
```